# How do you deploy multiple services on AWS Copilot at once?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

I'm new to AWS Copilot and containers in general (frontend focused engineer helping out with DevOps at my job) and am trying to figure out how to deploy multiple containers at once.  The project includes a web container, deployed through copilot as a Load Balanced Web Service, and a worker container, deployed as a Backend Service.  The two containers share a code base, so when I update one, I need to update the other, especially when there is a database migration.  When I do a copilot deploy, however, it seems to only give the option to choose one service.  How would I synchronize the deployment?

Answer (score 3):

You can deploy the two services in parallel by using Copilot's pipelines feature. Tons of info here: https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/concepts/pipelines/